# If I have three static send port say A , B and C .suppose if I received a file via port A if successful file should go to SEND PORT B else C Port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

If I have three static send port say A , B and C .suppose if I received a file via Send port A if successful  file should go to SEND PORT B else C Port without Orchestration.

Comment: You do this with filters on the send ports that match the promoted properties on the message that is received back.  As you haven't given any details about the messages, that is as best an answer as you will get at the moment.

Comment: The Message is XML format and I am using FILE adapter for this .In receive pipeline and send pipe line  I am using Pass through. As you said apply the filter which filter I have to apply and in which ports. Actually I  am new  on biztalk.

Thanks For the Response

Comment: You need to inspect the Context Properties of the response message on Port A and see what is in there and what is different between a successful a failed message.  And if the property that determines a success or failure is in the message body, you will want to use an XML dissasembler on the response and  also want to promote that property so it is in the context properties and you can use it in the filters.